# I have a string "pencil". the first three letters "pen" should change to "PEN". Can anyone help me?

Tags: c#

I have a string "pencil". The first three letters pen should change to "PEN". Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is the string variable ? If not you could just write `variable = "PENcil"`;

Comment: Yes. What have you tried?

Comment: I'm tempted to post "Yes, that is possible and yes, someone could help you" as an answer. But while technically answering everything that was asked, I am afraid it would still get me some downvotes.

Comment: This would've been solved faster on your end with a very fast Google Search. StackOverflow should restrict questions to a min of 200 characters or so.

Comment: This is as basic a research effort at it comes. Should not be a StackOverflow question, but part of basic programming / C# knowledge. - Like said above, Google or MSDN examples would answer this faster.

Answer (score 3):

You can't "change" a string.  You can create a *new* string and change some of the letters in-flight:

```
string s1 = "pencil";
string s2 = s1.Substring(0,3).ToUpper() + s1.Substring(3);
```

You can also, of course, *overwrite* the existing variable value:

```
string s1 = "pencil";
s1 = s1.Substring(0,3).ToUpper() + s1.Substring(3);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [String.Substring()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  and [String.ToUpper()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.toupper%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) functions to achieve this

```
 string str = "pencil";
 int lettersCount = 3;
 str = str.Substring(0, lettersCount ).ToUpper() + str.Substring(lettersCount );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Substring` and `ToUpper`:

```
int numChars = 3;
string pencil = "pencil";
if (pencil.Length >= numChars)
    pencil = pencil.Substring(0, numChars).ToUpper() + pencil.Substring(numChars);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string s = "pencil";

string str = new string(s.Select((c, index) => 
                     {
                         if (index < 3)
                             return Char.ToUpper(c);
                         else
                             return c;
                      }).ToArray());

Console.WriteLine(str); // output: PENcil
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.IO;
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
     string word = "pencil";
     string finalWord = word.Substring(0, 3).ToUpper() + word.Substring(3);
     Console.WriteLine(finalWord); //PENcil
    }
}
```